# Chrome Dev tools .har file for _webSocketTraffic has a "time" field - what does it mean?

Tags: google-chrome, websocket

I am trying to understand the websocketTraffic data exported from my Chrome dev tools. An example looks like this:

```
{
    'type': 'receive',
    'time': 1640291138.212745,
    'opcode': 1,
    'data': '<r xmlns=\'urn:xmpp:sm:3\'/>',
  }
```

I see a "time" field but I actually cant find anything about what it means except this from the spec (http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/har-12-spec/):

```
time [number] - Total elapsed time of the request in milliseconds. This is the sum of all timings available in the timings object (i.e. not including -1 values) .
```

Is this really milliseconds, down to the millionth of a millisecond? I am trying to see how much time has elapsed between two WS events, so any insight would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: I'm also wondering. The only reference they have in the docs is [this](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-76/#websocket), but it doesn't answer our question.

Comment: Ok, I have a hunch that the answer is this: move the dot 3 places to the right, (i.e `1640291138.212745 -> 1640291138212.745`) and you will get the actual time.
Try to run this 
`new Date(1640291138212.745).toISOString()`
and see if it fits your `startedDateTime` in the parent WebSocket entry in your har.

Comment: If my above solution is correct, then this means that Chrome saves the "time" field as [second since epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), instead of millisecond since epoch.
So "moving the dot 3 places to the right" actually means to multiply by a 1000 and that means converting to milliseconds.

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer:**

This answer is not backed by official docs. However, I studied this problem for quite some time now, and my solution seems to make sense.

**Answer:**

Move the dot 3 places to the right, (i.e `1640291138.212745 -> 1640291138212.745`) and you will get the actual time. Try to run this
`new Date(1640291138212.745).toISOString()`
and see if it fits your startedDateTime in the parent WebSocket entry in your har.

Probably Chrome saves the "time" field as [seconds since epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), instead of milliseconds since epoch. So "moving the dot 3 places to the right" actually means to multiply by a 1000 and that means converting to milliseconds.